# How Do Songlink and Songwhip Aggregate URLs from Multiple Streaming Platforms with One Link?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How do apps that enable users to post links to songs from various streaming platforms like Songwhip and Songlink return all relevant links, including for services like Amazon Music and Tidal that lack APIs?

As someone who'd like to implement a similar feature, where could I obtain data from?